# Android Making a shortcut key of my app?

Tags: android, shortcut

I am using an antivirus named "360 MobileSecurity" , and this app created an global shortcut key. That key is always visible for every applications. When I click on the key, it show's the functionality of antivirus. How can I do that kind of Shortcut of my app? I don't know what is the name of this kind of shortcut. Please help to find about this.

[image]

Comment: it's a key/widget,i think that is widget

Comment: This label only on home screen or over any application? Can you post screenshot with label over any application?

Comment: This label is not only on home screen. it shows always . like chatting  application of Facebook.